# Problem with authentication in REST WCF

Tags: wcf, heroku

I have developed REST WCF and set binding following way in web.config

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBasic">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour" >
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="RestService.CustomUsernamePasswordValidator, RestService"
                            userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
```

And in CustomUsernamePasswordValidator.cs file i have authenticate user by following way

```
namespace RestService
{
public class CustomUsernamePasswordValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!AuthenticateUser(userName, password))
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Invalid Username or Password");
    }

    private bool AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == "myaddon" && password == "mypassword")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

Now problem is that it is running nice when i will use this service from same project but confused that why this call would not occurred for validation?

Also when i test my heroku manifest addon file from ruby commnad propmpt it give me error of
Failed Authentication !! I think this is issue of my REST WCF Application.

Please anyone can help me to solve this issue if anyone know very well about WCF and authentication.

Thanks 
Arun.

Comment: Do you get any error message? You should perhaps change your password after posting it here :)

Comment: Authentication failed in Ruby command prompt.. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Please make your question title more informative: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-good-titles/10648#10648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have handle custom authentication using WebOperationContext directly and skip the Web.Config settings.